# Binding listbox to underlying Value in a Dictionary

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I am binding to an Observable Dictionary of type `ObservableDictionary<int, Person>` (although in this case I don't think it matters that it is Observable) and I can bind to this without an issue:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}">
```

However in my listbox template in order to access the underlying object I have to prefix all with value. Like the following:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="idValue" Text="{Binding Value.ID}" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

Which seems to work but what I was wondering is if it is possible to change the binding so that the Value prefix is unneeded? When I am using a data template it would feel better to me if it expected a type "Person"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Dictionary.Values as item source :

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary.Values}">
```

Comment: That does work, to a point. The refreshing of the listbox stops if I use this. This migth be to do with the particular implementation of the Dictionary I am using or something more but i am not totally sure

Comment: The collection returned by your ObservableDictionary.Values must be be observable.

Comment: have had a look at Dr WPF's implementation and reading the comments implies that getting it to work off Values is problematic. I had hoped there was a away in the XAMl to somehow say that the binding was against the `Value` but maybe I am just hitting the limitations of what I want to do